Apply json theme dynamically without conditional formatting in Power BI
Team,
I have two json files with different color themes. I want to apply both the themes dynamically on power Bi dashboard based on filters.
For example- If I clicked on Red, then Red Json theme should apply automatically. Vice versa for another color.

This is not possible with current capabilities.

@davidebacci - Can we hide and show bookmarks using Json

What do you mean? Which JSON? Bookmarks are triggered from user interactions only
